# Arch Linux Install Cannot Enable dhcpd

Tags: linux, arch-linux, dhcp, parallels, systemd

I am trying to setup internet with arch linux. I just installed it using parallels and got the following error:

```
[root@singularity ~]# systemctl enable dhcpd.service
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
```

So I tried linking it manually:

```
[root@singularity ~]# ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpd.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dhcpd.service
```

It was then that I realized that the file didn't even exist:

```
[root@singularity ~]# ls /usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpd.service
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpd.service: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way I can fix this? I do not have any internet access because I cannot enable dhcpd.
I am running OSX 10.9 and using parallels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Arch. I believe [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Configuration#Run_DHCP_at_boot) has the answers, it's what I used for the install on my laptop. In my case I ran `systemctl start dhcpcd@wlp3s0.service` since my wifi card is identified as wlp3s0, if you don't know for yours you can run `ifconfig` or specifically for wireless devices `iwconfig`.

Comment: That did it. I had to remember because I didn't install `iwconfig` or `ifconfig`

Answer (score 19):

While the question has been answered, I must add that the client daemon is called `dhcpcd`, **not** `dhcpd` (`dhcpd` is the DHCP server daemon). I spent twenty minutes trying to figure out why that was happening, and it was all because of a simple typo.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dhcpd) for dhcpd, the actual name of the service file is `dhcpd4.service`. Also make sure the `dhcp` package is installed.

Comment: That's not the right service. He's looking for dhcpCd.