# Arch Linux Install Cannot Enable dhcpcd

Tags: networking, installation, arch-linux, dhcp, dhcp-server

I am having problems using dhcpcd. I try running

```
systemctl enable dhcpcd@enp0s31f6
```

Returns Unit file dhcpcd@enp0s31f6.service does not exist. When I try running ip address, it outputs 3 options

`lo <LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER_UP> ...`

`enp0s31F6 <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> ...`

`wlp58s0 <NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> ...`

I have tried dhcpcd with the final 2 of the above just to run into the same error for both of them. In addition when I look in  /usr/lib/systemd/system/ I cannot find the dchpcd file.

Finally I tried 
`find / "dhcpcd.service"`
this returned no matches. I would appreciate any help/ clarification on why this occurs would be greatly appreciated. I know this is similar to

[Arch Linux Install Cannot Enable dhcpd](https://superuser.com/questions/700367/arch-linux-install-cannot-enable-dhcpd)

However the solution presented does not work for me.